# What is PAK_Generic.005 virus?

Tags: anti-virus

I scanned my files here [01](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/eab99e883f54627ef8752ae3036e6ed51aadb8d2b21f8b0a7b4562ec5c8b9aaa/analysis/1401071045/), [02](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/a2faa2f42ef4093a83cf89e3a2c0afbe540c7f46ededf86d75ced8fa732b0dac/analysis/1402119674/) and got detected at `PAK_Generic.005` virus.

What is this virus?

Comment: Sorry to be a poor sport, but have you tried [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=PAK_Generic.005). The [first result](http://about-threats.trendmicro.com/Malware.aspx?id=41068&name=PAK_GENERIC.005&language=en) indicates that it's how compressed files found by the Trend Micro's heuristic algorithm are classified.

Comment: Oh of course I did google before I asked. Indeed, I google for `PAK_Generic.005 virustotal` and that give me nowhere helpful except this question ^^

Comment: The `virustotal` string is *polluting* the results. Virustotal, in essence, just runs whatever file you send to it through a batter of AV software. **Each** AV software has its own way of declaring viruses. In your case, *only* Trend Micro AVs detected the file as  potentially harmful. Looking at the link I gave earlier, this is due to the heuristic algorithm. In other words, some parts of the file *resemble* parts that *generic* viruses have. The `PAK` part relates to the executable, which is [packed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_packer).

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Please move your comment into an answer to get accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=PAK_Generic.005) for the virus' designation lead me to [this](http://about-threats.trendmicro.com/Malware.aspx?id=41068&name=PAK_GENERIC.005&language=en) page by Trend Micro (which was the only AV suite that found the virus pointed to by the OP).

Virustotal, in essence, just runs whatever file you send to it through a batter of AV software. Each AV software has its own way of declaring viruses. In your case, only Trend Micro AVs detected the file as potentially harmful.

Looking at the link I gave earlier, this is due to the heuristic algorithm Trend Micro uses. In order to detect viruses, it's not like every AV has a copy of every single virus in existence; not only that would be impossible, but potentially dangerous.

So, AV suites scan files using a large set of rules - this is usually called an heuristic algorithm. In this case, this algorithm detected 2 things, which are reported as the virus' name:

- Some parts of the file resemble parts that **generic** viruses have (they may delete, modify, index system files, for instance).
- The PAK part relates to the executable, which is **[packed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_packer)**. Packing is an identical process to compression, where in order to reduce the executable's size, it has a compressed version of itself and another piece of software that decompresses it. Although there are good reasons to pack executables, the same reasons can also be applied to viral software (smaller files ease propagation).